# Ubuntu 20.04 can not enter the desktop after entering cold password authentication

Tags: 20.04

I installed ubuntu 20.04 and window 10 dual system, when I boot directly into ubuntu, I cannot enter the desktop after verifying the password, however, I enter window 10 and then restart into ubuntu to enter the ubuntu desktop, which is independent of the ASUS I use For a laptop with a graphics card, I have installed the latest proprietary graphics driver, but this does not work. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this issue very consistently as I am installing Ubuntu as a dual-boot system on an entire fleet of ASUS laptops from the X450 and X455 range. Without fail, this is how I resolved the issue.

1. Install Ubuntu (or re-install in your case)
2. Drop into TTY as soon as you first boot into Ubuntu, e.g. Ctrl+Alt+F3.
3. Run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y`. For some reason during this stage the Desktop session will sometimes snatch away the screen from TTY and you will have to switch back to it.
4. Reboot after the upgrade and wait for everything to load in Ubuntu. I have not seen the problematic behaviour repeat itself since.